# What to code in Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml to pass local package in docker environment

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I introduced `local package` with `go modules` for server side api. 
It works fine in local environment without error by commanding `go run main.go`.

But it does not work when commanding `docker-compose up`.

**I want to know what to code Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml to fix.**

I command `go mod init` at `article` directory.

As result, it sets `module github.com/jpskgc/article` in `go.mod`.

```
article
  ├ db
  ├ client
  ├ api
  │  ├ main.go
  │  ├ controller
  │  │    └ controller.go
  │  └ Dockerfile
  ├ nginx
  ├ docker-compose.yml
  ├ go.mod
  └ go.sum
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "os"
    "time"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller"
)
    api := router.Group("/api")
    {
        api.GET("/articles", func(c *gin.Context) {
            controller.GetArticleController(c, db)
        })
    }
    router.Run(":2345")
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest
ENV GO111MODULE=on
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/jpskgc/article/app
COPY . .
RUN go mod download
RUN go build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/src/github.com/jpskgc/article/app/api"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/go/src/github.com/jpskgc/article/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_HOST
      - GO111MODULE
```

go.mod

```
module github.com/jpskgc/article

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.23.7
    github.com/gin-contrib/cors v1.3.0
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.4.0
    github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.4.1
    github.com/google/uuid v1.1.1
    github.com/joho/godotenv v1.3.0
)
```

I expect server side api working fine without error in docker environment.
But the actual is that docker environment for server side fails to run.

Here is error message when commanding docker-compose up

```
build command-line-arguments: 
cannot load github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller: 
cannot find module providing package github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller
article_api_1 exited with code 1
```

Here is the entire source code on github (branch: try-golang-mod).
I wish someone to give me answer code for `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.
https://github.com/jpskgc/article/tree/try-golang-mod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue in following way.

1. `go mod init article/api` at `api` directory.

```
article
  ├ client
  ├ api
  │  ├ main.go
  │  ├ contoroller
  │  │    └ contoroller.go
  │  ├ //
  │  ├ go.mod 
  │  ├ go.sum
  │  └ Dockerfile
  ├ nginx
  ├ go.mod
  ├ go.sum
  └ docker-compose.yml
```

2. fix `Docekrfile`

```
FROM golang:latest
ENV GO111MODULE=on
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/api"]
```

3. command `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 1):

Your docker context is ./api, but the go.mod is in the parent directory, so go.mod is not included in your image.

One option could be to change your docker context to the root directory of the source tree (parent of api), and copy the files/directories into the image from there.